# Cannot cast datetime.timedelta object from metadata [Y] to [D] according to the rule 'same_kind'

Tags: python-3.x

My code looks as follow:

```
import pandas as pd
import quandl as qdl
from scipy.stats import linregress

# get AAPL 10 years data

data = qdl.get("WIKI/AAPL", start_date="2011-01-01", end_date="2017-05-01")

data0 = data.copy()
data0['date_id'] = ((data0.index.date - data0.index.date.min())).astype('timedelta64[D]')
```

But when I run it I got following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot cast datetime.timedelta object from metadata [Y] to [D] according to the rule 'same_kind'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime

data0['date_id'] = ((data0.index.date - data0.index.date.min())).astype(datetime)
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it?